# Issues with a TextField element from a Sub component in React using Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

ok, so I have a functional component which is effectively a mini Text Editor. It allow user to select Font, Font Size and Colour. This form contains below TextField element.

```
<Box
        
        sx={{
          "& .MuiTextField-root": { marginTop: 3, width: "80ch" },
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <div>
          <TextField
            id="textMessage"
            name="textMessage"
            label="Message"
            multiline={true}
            rows={6}
            defaultValue={mainMessageText}
            onChange={handleChangeText}
            //onBlur={handleBlur}
            //helperText={touched.message ? errors.message : ""}
            //error={touched.message && Boolean(errors.message)}
            inputProps={{
              maxLength: 320,
              minLength: 9,
              style: {
                //fontWeight: boldButtonState ? "bold" : "",
                //fontStyle: italicButtonState ? "italic" : "",
                //fontSize: fontSize,
                //fontFamily: selectedFont,
                lineHeight: "1em",
                //textDecoration: underlinedButtonState ? "underline" : "",
                //color: fontColor,
              },
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </Box>
```

In my one of the other functional component, I am trying to use the above Text Editor sub component under Formik as per below.. **when I submit the form, the handleSubmit event doesn't have value of the textMessage.. is there something I am missing?** I've used this type of sub\common components in other projects and never had any issues so long as the 'name' value of the TextField matches with the initialValues element.

```
<Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Item 
                          sx={{
                            width: "50em",
                            height: "20em",
                            variant: "outlined",
                            border: "solid",
                          }}
                        >
                        
                         <MyTextEditor 
                            message={message}
                            touched={touched}
                            errors={errors}
                            handleBlur={handleBlur}
                            updateMessageText={setMessage}
                            updateFontSize={setFontSize}
                            updateFontFamily={setFontFamily}
                            updateBoldFontStyle={setBoldFontStyle}
                            updateItalicFontStyle={setItalicFontStyle}
                            updateFontColor={setFontColor}
                            handleDraw={handleDraw}
                          />
                        </Item>
                      </Grid>

My Formik initialValues is defined as per below ...

const initialValues = {
    textMessage: ""
  };

and Formik code which embeds the Text Editor component is as per below ...

return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        //enableReinitialize
      >
        {({
          submitForm,
          handleBlur,
          handleChange,
          isSubmitting,
          isValid,
          dirty,
          touched,
          values,
          errors,
        }) => (
          <Form>
             <div>
               <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Item 
                          sx={{
                            width: "50em",
                            height: "20em",
                            variant: "outlined",
                            border: "solid",
                          }}
                        >
                        
                         <MyTextEditor 
                            message={message}
                            touched={touched}
                            errors={errors}
                            handleBlur={handleBlur}
                            updateMessageText={setMessage}
                            updateFontSize={setFontSize}
                            updateFontFamily={setFontFamily}
                            updateBoldFontStyle={setBoldFontStyle}
                            updateItalicFontStyle={setItalicFontStyle}
                            updateFontColor={setFontColor}
                            handleDraw={handleDraw}
                          />
                        </Item>
                      </Grid>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        //color="green"
                        size="medium"
                        //className={classes.buttonGreen}
                        startIcon={<EmailIcon />}
                        //</Grid>disabled={
                        //  !(isValid && touched && dirty) || isSubmitting
                        //}
                        onClick={() => {
                          submitForm();
                        }}
                      >
                        Submit Form
                      </Button>
                <div>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
```